# Appengine HTTPS secure:always causes a redirect loop with CloudFlare

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, redirect, https, cloudflare

When setting secure to always on app.yaml all I get is endless 302 redirects when trying to load the http or the https version of the website.

```
application: xxx
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

default_expiration: "200d"

handlers:

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon.ico

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt

- url: /fonts
  static_dir: fonts

- url: /styles
  static_dir: styles

- url: /scripts
  static_dir: scripts

- url: /images/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|svg))$
  static_files: images/\1
  upload: images/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|svg)$

- url: /.*
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
  secure: always
```

It is an angular app, that's why I'm handling all URLs on index.html

[image: browser redirects]

[image: network inspector]

[image: appengine logs]

```
curl -L --dump-header /tmp/head example.org

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2015 13:57:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d82f41e169b9140f8a0e3cb1b2ac5b1de1450879051; expires=Thu, 22-Dec-16 13:57:31 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.org; HttpOnly
Location: https://example.org/
CF-RAY: 2594937966dd18c1-GRU

... 48 more of these ...

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2015 13:57:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d82f41e169b9140f8a0e3cb1b2ac5b1de1450879051; expires=Thu, 22-Dec-16 13:57:31 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.org; HttpOnly
Location: https://example.org/
CF-RAY: 2594937966dd18c1-GRU
```

---

```
curl -L --dump-header /tmp/head myppid.appspot.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://myppid.appspot.com/
Date: Tue, 22 Dec 2015 18:20:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 22 Dec 2015 18:20:23 GMT
Expires: Sat, 09 Jul 2016 18:20:23 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=17280000
ETag: "0tVHeg"
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 11144
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=604800; v="30,29,28,27,26,25"
```

Cloudflare sits in front of my appengine app with the following SSL option:

[image: cloudflare setting]

So what's going on here? Do I need to add an SSL certificate to AppEngine and switch the SSL mode to full to actually get it to work properly? I don't get why it's redirecting to http and then back to https when passing through CloudFlare.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with  `curl -L --dump-header /tmp/head http://myappid.appspot.com/` -- this results in a /tmp/head with exactly the two predicted stanzas (the 302 Found with Location: https...etc.. then the 200 OK) and the right result. Of course I can't tell exactly what's happening w/your browser and/or your angular/JS code wrt following the redirect. Can you try this curl and edit your question to post the /tmp/head? This will help us see the problem in more detail, if it's in app engine at all -- or show that GAE is fine and there's a bug in your JS code.

Comment: @AlexMartelli That did not provide any clues. I'm starting a new project and will try to reproduce. The angular code is not reached at all, I believe it's AppEngine related.

Comment: @AlexMartelli Oh... There's cloudflare too. I forgot about cloudflare.

Comment: Temporarily setting secure to optional on app.yaml and creating page rules on cloudflare to forward traffic to https on both the naked domain and any subdomains.